# After branching from FB, get GitHub PR to only show differences between FB and master

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-flow, feature-branch

We have the following situation:

```
master ------A          X------------Y
              \        / \          /
               \      /   \        /
                \    /     \      /
                 --B-       \    / 
                    \        \  /
                     C---------D
```

Jane has created a FB at A, then merged back at X.

Bob created FB C at B, did some work, pulled again from master, and has created a PR at D to merge back at Y.

In GitHub, Jane's PR correctly showed only changes between A and X and was merged back in to master.

In GitHub, Bob's PR shows ALL the changes between **A** and Y, which isn't what we expected.  We thought that because Bob merged from X into his FB at D, that his PR would only include the changes between his branch and **X**, that is the *current* difference between his branch and master.

Are we missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by pulled again from master? Like he updated the FB C by pulling changes from origin/master?

Comment: Yes @AElMehdi, that's what I meant - he updated FB C by merging X at point D.  I've updated the post to be clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebase interactively you `feature branch c` on `origin/master` and `force push` to your `feature branch c`.

1. Update your local repository:

   ```
   git fetch
   ```
2. Switch to your feature-branch C:

   ```
   git checkout feature-branch-c
   ```
3. Run an interactive rebase on the origin/master:

   ```
   git rebase -i origin/master
   ```

You'll be prompted to change the **history**, be careful ;):

```
pick 2feec74 message1
pick 2xxxx m2
pick 2xxxx m3
pick xxxx m4
```

This will contain the same commits you see in your github PR. Now you can simply remove the unneeded commits by prefixing them with a `d` like so:

```
pick 2feec74 message1
d 2xxxx m2  (The commit you want to drop)
d 2xxxx m3  (The commit you want to drop)
pick xxxx m4
```

Save your file, and now you can push again but you'll need to use the flag `-f` since you've change the history.

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AEIMehdi, I hoped a rebase wasn't going to be the answer.  :-/    I'm sure in a previous GitHub setup, in this scenario, that the PR seemed to auto-detect that only the differences from X to Y were now relevant.

Is there another way, without a rebase?

Comment: You're more than welcome! There will be surely another way to fix it.  Is it a public repository?

Comment: No, it's not public.    After talking to other git users in our company, they've also seen the case where only differences X->Y are part of the PR.

Comment: Check the hash of the duplicated commits, I guess they will be different!